# Probability Density Function with Zero Standard Deviation

Tags: bayesian, gaussian, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I am now implementing an email filtering application using the Naive Bayes algorithm. My application uses the Spambase Data Set from the UCI Machine Learning Repository. Since the attributes are continuous, I calculate the probability using the Probability Density Function (PDF). However, when I evaluate the data using the k-fold cross validation, a training set may contain only 0 for one of its attributes. For this reason, I got a 0 standard deviation and the PDF returns NaN and it leads to a huge number of spams are not correctly classified with that training set. What should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: You should pose at as a statistical problem to the [Stats SO forum](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), or to the [Statistics subforum](http://www.physicsforums.com/forumdisplay.php?f=78) of the Physics Forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a discrete PDF, which will always be bounded.

Alternatively, simply ignore any attribute with zero variance.  There is no point in including distributions with zero variance, because they won't actually *do* anything.  For example, you want to know how old I am, and then I tell you that I live on planet Earth.  That shouldn't change your estimate, because every single piece of data you have is for people on planet Earth.

Comment: I think I will just ignore attributes with zero variance then, thanks!